# Max / Min calculation for a list (Python)

Tags: python

I guess I didn’t search for the right keyword so ended not founding an existing answer….
I’m trying to get the best way of getting the max or min of a 2 lists with same length, taking the max or min of each position.

I got to a point as below

```
Input A = 725324
Input B = 9341
```

Expected Max calculation of A & B would be 729344 (taking the max number on that position)

I got to the point only aligning 2 numbers to have same digits, and zipped the 2 strings, then got stuck with below list… the way I’m going towards will be `Max(L[1])`, `Max(L[2])`…all the way to `Max(L[digits - 1])`,but not sure what’s the best way of expressing it in Python and if that’s the right approach.

```
List = [(7, 0), (2, 0), (5, 9), (3, 3), (2, 4), (4, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string padding `str.rjust()` to properly pad the "shorter" number:

```py
a = 725324
b = 9341

a, b = map(str, (a, b))
w = max(map(len, (a, b)))

result = ""
for t in zip(a.rjust(w, "0"), b.rjust(w, "0")):
    result += max(t)

result = int(result)
```

Output:

```py
729344
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach we can use for this problem is to use math (division and remainders):

```
a = 725324
b = 9341

digits = 0
num = 0
while a != 0 or b != 0:
  if a != 0 and b != 0:
    num += 10 ** digits * max(a % 10, b % 10)
    a //= 10
    b //= 10
  elif a != 0:
    num += 10 ** digits * (a % 10)
    a //= 10
  else:
    num += 10 ** digits * (b % 10)
    b //= 10
  digits += 1
print(num)
```

With this code, we will enter a while loop **while** either  `a` or `b` is nonzero.

From there, if both `a` and `b` are nonzero, then we find which number has the greatest last digit, which we calculate by doing `% 10`. We then scale it up so that we can add it to a total variable, `num` by storing the number of digits we have added, `digits`, and raising `10` to the power of `digits` and multiplying that value by the remainder.

We then do this same process for if only `a` or if only `b` are nonzero, but without taking the other variable into account.

I hope this helped! Please let me know if you need any further clarification or details :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another pure numerical solution using `divmod` and powers of 10:

```
def max_digit(A,B):
    out = 0
    exp = 0
    if A < B: # ensure looping on the largest number
        B,A = A,B
    while A>0:
        A,a = divmod(A,10) # get unit and shift
        B,b = divmod(B,10)
        out += (10**exp)*max(a,b)
        exp += 1
    return out

A = 725324
B =   9341

max_digit(A,B)
# 729344
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem well so here is my solution

```
def maximum_digits():
    a = input("nummber a :")
    b = input("nummber b :")

    # finding the difference lenght between two number
    c = len(a) - len(b)

    # making a list of each digits in a number so 725324 >>> [7,2,5,3,2,4]
    list_a = []
    a=int(a)
    while a > 0:
        list_a.append(a % 10)
        a //= 10

    list_b = []
    b=int(b)
    while b > 0:
        list_b.append(b % 10)
        b //= 10

    # making the two number have same lenght by adding zero
    if a >= b:
        for k in range(c):
            list_b.append(0)

    else:
        for k in range(c):
            list_a.append(0)

    final_list = []
    for i, j in zip(list_a, list_b):
        if i > j:
            final_list.append(i)
        else:
            final_list.append(j)

    number = ""
    for i in final_list[::-1]:
        number += str(i)

    return number

print(maximum_digits())
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @ddejohn written even shorter:

```py
a = 725324
b = 9341

a, b = map(str, (a, b))
w = max(map(len, (a, b)))

result = int("".join(max(t) for t in zip(a.rjust(w, "0"), b.rjust(w, "0"))))
```